# Match and concatenate vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, multiple-matches

I have data like this

```
      A      B   C   D
1. Customer T/C NET VAT
2.  Sandy    T1
3.  Sandy    T5
4.  Sandy    T1
5.  Sandy    T5
6.  Candy    T1
7.  Candy    T5
8.  Dandy    T5
9.  Dandy    T1
```

Where `NET` and `VAT` contains `$Amount` & `1,2` etc are row numbers & T1/T5 are TaxCodes

> Summary Columns

```
      R        S      T
1. Customer  T5NET  T5VAT
2.  Sandy 
3.  Candy 
4.  Dandy
```

I want to summarize `NET` + `VAT` with `cell.address` in Summary columns respectively in front of the Customer.

> Example: Summary Columns

```
       R        S      T
 1. Customer  T5NET  T5VAT
 2.  Sandy   =C3+C5  =D3+D5
 3.   etc
```

I'm assuming I'll need a `Match` function to Match `#1 Customer` (Summary to Database) and `#2 T5` then Concatenate the offset values against summarized name.

Editied Now (This is close but how do I alter it for match function?)

```
`Sub MatchConcanate()
Dim outputText As String, Rw As Range, cell As Range
delim = "+"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Select
For Each Rw In Selection.Columns
'Here I want it to only Select Supplier till it is duplicate (they are sorted) and then to next
    For Each cell In Rw.Cells
    If cell.Value = "T5" Then
        outputText = outputText & delim & cell.Address
    End If
    Next cell
    With Rw
'Here I'd like a match function instead of pasting it all in cell 1
    .Cells(1).Offset(0, 5).Value = outputText
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    End With
    outputText = ""
Next Rw
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

Push everything right one column and put in A1 "=B1 & C2" . e.g. Customer and T/C

Then in your columns you want sum's use a sumif

```
Name T1 T2
Sandy =SUMIF(A:A,S2&$T$1,D:D) =SUMIF(A:A,S2&$U$1,D:D)
Candy =SUMIF(A:A,S3&$T$1,D:D) =SUMIF(A:A,S3&$U$1,D:D)
Dandy =SUMIF(A:A,S4&$T$1,D:D) =SUMIF(A:A,S4&$U$1,D:D)
```

Ranges have moved over one due to the new column "A"

Comment: Review team checks and changes through the links only, and sumif wont cut it. Need specific links in the summary sheet.

Comment: I dont understand you sentence... I had the above solution working here